# get iOS 7 udid without access to a computer?

Tags: ios7, itunes, udid

I need to ask my clients to send me the udid of their iOS devices in order to add them to an adhoc distribution profile. The main problem is that they are used to iOS but not much to computers. Anyway, it would be a pain for me to explain them how to install iTunes (or even Xcode) to get the udid. Most of the tutorials which describe the iTunes process are in english, I don't want to loose time to translate one of them. And even if I do it, I fear that they will not appreciate loosing their time following it. Any suggestion ?

Comment: Since in iOS7 you won't get the UUID of the device (deprecated, and if still the old method, it would return a "false" UUID), you won't be able to do it without a computer...
Utilitary of Configuration iPhone could be a lighter way to get it than iTunes.

Comment: eh: http://get.udid.io takes about 30 seconds

Comment: You can find using http://udidiphone.com along with UDID you can get IMEI, Serial Number, Device and OS details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a web online tool at http://www.easy-udid.com to get my customers UDID, I think it's the easiest way for them.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use service http://udid.io

It is easier because you don't need to ask your clients to write your email address. You just send them link “http://get.udid.io/?mail=your@mail.com” and they will need only 5 taps to send UDID on "your@mail.com"